# Prove matrix derivative identity

Tags: matrices, derivatives

I found the following identity in the [Matrix Cookbook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/3274/pdf/imm3274.pdf):

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial }{\partial X} \text{Trace}\left( X B X ^{\mathrm{T}} \right) = XB^{\mathrm{T}} + XB,
\end{align*}

where $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and $B\in\mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$. Any hints on how I prove this?

Comment: "Old and New Matrix Algebra Useful for Statistics" this article might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to expand the matrix product:

$\begin{align*}
Trace(XBX^{T})&=\sum_{i}(XBX^{T})_{ii}=\sum_{i}\sum_{j}X_{ij}(BX^{T})_{ji}=\sum_{i}\sum_{j}X_{ij}\sum_{k}B_{jk}X^{T}_{ki}=\\
&=\sum_{i}\sum_{j}\sum_{k}X_{ij}B_{jk}X^{T}_{ki}=\sum_{i}\sum_{j}\sum_{k}X_{ij}B_{jk}X_{ik}
\end{align*}$

Then

$\begin{align*}
\frac{{\partial}}{{\partial}(X_{ij},X_{ik})}Trace(XBX^{T})&=\sum_{k}B_{jk}X_{ik}\,+\,\sum_{j}X_{ij}B_{jk}=\sum_{k}B^{T}_{kj}X_{ik}\,+\,\sum_{j}X_{ij}B_{jk}\\
&=(XB^{T})_{ij}\,+\,(XB)_{ik}
\end{align*}$

And summing over all partial derivatives gives the result.

Answer (score 1):

**A solution avoiding to use the coordinates.**

Note $f : \mathbb{R}^{n\times m} \to \mathbb R$ where
$$f(X) = \text{Trace}\left( X B X ^{\mathrm{T}} \right)$$

You have $f=h \circ g$ where $g(X) = X B X ^{\mathrm{T}}$ and $h(Y) = \text{Trace}(Y)$.

According to the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions) you have
$$(h \circ g)^\prime (X) = (h^\prime(g(X)) \circ g^\prime(X)$$

$h$ is a linear map. So its (Fréchet) dérivative is
$$h^\prime(Y).V = \text{Trace}(V)$$

On its side, $g$ is a bilinear map. So we have
$$g^\prime(X).U = U B X ^{\mathrm{T}} + X B U ^{\mathrm{T}}$$

Using the chain rule with the above derivatives, you get
$$f^\prime(X).U = \text{Trace}(U B X ^{\mathrm{T}} + X B U ^{\mathrm{T}})$$

As $\text{Trace}$ is linear and $\text{Trace}(X)=\text{Trace}(X^{\mathrm{T}})$ for all square matrix, we also have

$$f^\prime(X).U = \text{Trace}((X B^{\mathrm{T}}  + X B)U ^{\mathrm{T}})$$

Which is exactly the result you're looking for.